# Resampling of Sentinel-1 data to 1km resolution using gdal and snappy modules

Tags: gdalwarp, rasterio, gdal-translate, resampling, sentinel-snap

I am trying to resample my preprocessed Sentinel-1 data to 1km resolution. I am facing the following issues when I try to do it using snappy and gdal modules.

**Using gdal**,

Used code:

```py
os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff -tr 1000 1000 -r {average} terrain_corrected.tif resampled.tif')
```

Output:

Input file size is 12545, 12811

ERROR 5: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal.

Used code:

```py
resampled = gdal.Warp("D:/.../resampled2.tif", image, warpOptions=dict(format = 'GTiff', xRes = 1000, yRes = 1000, resampleAlg = gdal.GRA_Average))
```

Output:
The output image is getting generated but has the same resolution as the input

**Using snappy,**

Used code:

```
parameters = HashMap()

parameters.put('targetResolution', '10')

resampled = GPF.createProduct('Resample', parameters, speckle_filter_tc)
```

Output:
Whatever size the input image is I am still getting the same error mentioning the same height and width

```
SEVERE: org.esa.snap.core.util.SystemUtils$SnapImagingListener: JAI error occurred: 'Problem occurs when computing a tile by the owner.' at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@7ecb4a80
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=111321 height=111321) are too large
        at java.awt.image.SampleModel.<init>(SampleModel.java:130)
        at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.<init>(ComponentSampleModel.java:146)
        at javax.media.jai.ComponentSampleModelJAI.<init>(ComponentSampleModelJAI.java:73)
        at org.esa.snap.core.util.jai.SingleBandedSampleModel.<init>(SingleBandedSampleModel.java:62)
        at org.esa.snap.core.util.jai.SingleBandedSampleModel.createCompatibleSampleModel(SingleBandedSampleModel.java:79)
        at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getExtendedData(PlanarImage.java:2451)
        at javax.media.jai.GeometricOpImage.computeTile(GeometricOpImage.java:678)
        at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler.scheduleTile(SunTileScheduler.java:904)
        at javax.media.jai.OpImage.getTile(OpImage.java:1129)
        at javax.media.jai.PointOpImage.computeTile(PointOpImage.java:911)
        at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler.scheduleTile(SunTileScheduler.java:904)
        at javax.media.jai.OpImage.getTile(OpImage.java:1129)
        at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2085)
        at com.bc.ceres.glevel.MultiLevelImage.getData(MultiLevelImage.java:64)
        at org.esa.snap.core.dataio.ProductIO.writeTile(ProductIO.java:602)
        at org.esa.snap.core.dataio.ProductIO.lambda$writeRasterDataFully$0(ProductIO.java:578)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Input Image Details using gdalinfo

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
[image]

Comment: What are the resolution and coordinate system of the source image? Use gdalinfo for checking.

Comment: The coordinate system of your image is EPSG:4326, units are degrees, and pixel size of 1000 units means that one pixel would wrap the Earth about three times. That is the reason for the error stating that 0 by 0 sized raster is impossible.

Comment: In that case should I reproject it before resampling or is there any other alternative?

Comment: Decide first in what coordinate system you want to use the data. You can naturally change the pixel size also when in EPSG:4326 by using reasonable values. The native seems to be `0.000089831`.

Comment: Thankyou so much, it worked.